# Picture Size in Android Studio with Java

Tags: java, android, image, camera, size

This is a beginner question, so I apologize if it is very basic.  I have googled and searched, but the questions/answers I've found are far more complex than I am capable of understanding.   I am trying to make a camera app for Android in Android Studio.  I know I can access the default camera, but I need to do it from within the app.

So far my app does show a preview, and can take and save pictures successfully.

I am following the camera API page here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

I need to understand how to set the picture size.  For now I am okay with setting it directly/statically to 2048 x 1536.

This seems to be the correct command/function to use here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int, int)

It gives me this:  void setPictureSize (int width, int height)

> ***My question is*** -  where and how do I implement this?   (If I add "setPictureSize(2048,1536)" anywhere in my code, it turns up with a
>   red line and says "cannot resolve method.")

Is there some prefix, like "Camera.setPictureSize..." I don't see any option to import the required class/method.

Comment: can you post the code on where you are getting the image and how ?, also , you cant set the resolution of the camera , but you can resize the image taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out how to [Modify Camera Settings](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#TaskSettings) for more detail but, for setPictureSize, you use it by retrieving the Camera.Parameters from your Camera instance, change what you need, and set them back on the camera.  Assuming your Camera instance is called `mCamera`:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setPictureSize(width, height); 
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: Two comments on this. First, we cannot choose an arbitrary size; we must query `params.getSupportedPIctureSizes()` and we are allowed to use only the pairs that appear in the returned list of sizes. Second, this setting should be performed after `Camera.open()`, but before `Camera.startPreview()`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Out of curiosity, what happens if you pick an arbitrary size instead of using one of the sizes returned by getSupportedPictureSizes()?  The Camera.Parameters documentation doesn't mention this seemingly very important caveat of setPictureSize. Presumably mCamera.setParameters will throw a RuntimeException?

Comment: Just to clarify, in the last line above, should "parameters" be changed to "params"?

mCamera.setParameters(params); <-- like this?

Comment: UPDATE: I did change it to "params" and it does work.  I also set the size manually, which also worked, but I know I need (eventually) to set the size in a more sophisticated manner.  Thanks for the help!